# Oracle 11g MTS install fails with error: OUI - 10150: Error: A runtime exception occurred while setting s_dlgCfgNamingLabelSIDnull

Tags: installation, oracle, oracle-11g, msdtc

Is there a workaround in the Oracle 11g Universal Installer for the following error?

`OUI - 10150: Error: A runtime exception occurred while setting s_dlgCfgNamingLabelSIDnull in component oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.1.0. installation cannot continue for this component`

It occurs when I run the Universal Installer on Windows 2008 Server after installing the core database components.

I'm trying to install MTS support using the 'Custom' option which only seems to be available post install.

Comment: Are you running the installer from $ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin?  To avoid this error, always run OUI from the installation media and not from $ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin.

Comment: @Optichip Running the OUI from the installation media does not give me the 'Custom' option I need to install MTS.

Answer (score 0):

This release is like too old. You should try at least 11.2.0.5.x.
And the beast way to solve problems it to search the metalink, not here.